# Entity extraction from bank wire transactions ( like not-so-natural-text)

Tags: nlp, nltk, opennlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract entities ( name , address , organization) from not so natural text, like comment in bank wire transactions.
Obviously not getting good results , used NLTK , OpenNLP and CoreNLP.

Any idea how to improve the results?

the text can look like,

1. EVERITT 620122T NAT ABC INDIA LTD
2. REF ROBERT FINEMANN  - REASON SHOP RENTAL
3. REF BY92 00 112233999 - REASON SPEEDING FINE
4. GEM SS HEUTIGEM SCHIENDLER
5. PENSION CH1234  CAB28

...

Reference to research work or existing products will also help

Comment: You might have to "pay" for such service ;P

Answer (score 1):

if you're using opennlp and know how to train, you should give 15000 examples in the training data which can look like

```
 <START:name> EVERITT <END> <START:Address> 620122T NAT <END> <START:Organisation> ABC INDIA LTD <END>
.......
....(15000 lines)
```

and then you can expect some good results!

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me you'll have to use a dictionary/database.

You could try growing one using a procedure like this: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/papers/eacl2014.pdf

But you'll still need to have a way of defining candidate "phrases" -- examples from the paper, e.g. capitalized words, won't work here obviously.